# Apache Web server using fcgi

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-fcgid, eiffel

I have web application server that handles requests and returns response created in Eiffel web framework and uses fcgi as a connector, and I have put the final executable file in the htdocs file (app.exe).

Now I want to run apache with fastcgi and start the application and run it in localhost.
I modified the httpconf file as below, but its not running.

```
<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    Options +ExecCGI +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>

    AddHandler fcgid-script .ews
    FcgidWrapper C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/app.exe .ews

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ app.ews [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !service.ews
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ service.ews/$1
    RewriteRule .* ­ [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

</IfModule>
```

I have loaded the 2 modules fcgid and rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The apache configuration is correct, and after investigating this issue with the user but it appeared that app.exe was not compiled to be run as a libfcgi server but as a standalone server.

With EWF , it is possible to compile the same code to run as CGI, standalone server of libfcgi, or all of them but in this case, the name of the executable matters.
This was the error.
The user fixed his error and is not able to run its application as a FCGI server.

Comment: is not or is now?